# WPF: rotating controls using mouse movements around a point

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have code (below) that allows me to rotate 4 elements (imRotationOverlay, imBoat, imRotationPanel, imRotationPanel2) around the mid point of imBoat based on Mouse Movements.  This works until it hits angles between 246 and 304.  I was wondering where the problem in my code is that didn't allow for rotation in these angles to happen.

```
Dim MousePoint As Point
Private Sub RotationMouseDown() Handles imRotationPanel.MouseDown, imRotationPanel2.MouseDown
    MousePoint = Mouse.GetPosition(Application.Current.MainWindow)
End Sub
Sub RotationMouseMove(sender As Image, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles imRotationPanel.MouseMove, imRotationPanel2.MouseMove
    If e.LeftButton = MouseButtonState.Pressed Then
        Dim midPointOfControl As Point
        midPointOfControl.X = imBoat.Margin.Left + (0.5 * imBoat.Width)
        midPointOfControl.Y = imBoat.Margin.Top + (0.5 * imBoat.Width)
        Dim opposite, adjacent, hypotenuse As Integer
        opposite = midPointOfControl.Y - MousePoint.Y
        adjacent = midPointOfControl.X - MousePoint.X
        hypotenuse = Math.Sqrt(opposite ^ 2 + adjacent ^ 2)
        Dim angle As Integer = Math.Acos(adjacent / hypotenuse)
        If imRotationPanel.IsMouseOver = True Then
            angle = -angle
        End If
        angle = angle + GetAngle(imBoat)
        RotateAllBy(angle)
        MousePoint = Mouse.GetPosition(Me)
    End If '58 degrees of error... (246-304[-56] where angle [first declaration] returns as 0)
End Sub
Sub RotateAllBy(ByVal angle As Integer)
    Rotate(imBoat, angle, imBoat.Width / 2, imBoat.Height / 2)
    Rotate(imRotationOverlay, angle, 0.5, 0.5)
    Rotate(imRotationPanel2, angle, 0, (imRotationOverlay.Height / 2) - 4)
    Rotate(imRotationPanel, angle, imRotationPanel.Width, (imRotationOverlay.Height / 2) - 4)
End Sub
Private Sub Rotate(sender As Object, ByVal rotationAmount As Integer, ByVal centerX As Integer, ByVal centerY As Integer)
    Dim rotateTransform As New RotateTransform(rotationAmount)
    rotateTransform.CenterX = centerX
    rotateTransform.CenterY = centerY
    sender.RenderTransform = rotateTransform
End Sub
Private Function GetAngle(sender As Object) As Integer
    Dim rotateTransform As New RotateTransform
    rotateTransform = sender.RenderTransform
    Return rotateTransform.Angle
End Function
```

Thanks all

EDIT:  Could this code be improved if the control just pointed towards the mouse?  If so, how would I code this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes simpler is better

```
Private Sub RotationMouseMove(sender As Image, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles imRotationPanel.MouseMove, imRotationPanel2.MouseMove
    If e.LeftButton = MouseButtonState.Pressed Then
        Dim angle As Integer = 1
        If imRotationPanel.IsMouseOver = True Then
            angle = -angle
        End If
        angle = angle + GetAngle(imBoat)
        RotateAllBy(angle)
        MousePoint = Mouse.GetPosition(Me)
    End If
End Sub
```

**Edit:**

What was wrong: angle defined in the original solution was giving too small a value to increment it by in the 246-304 section.

What I did differently: made the angle a set value thus decreasing the complexity of the original code

Why this worked: the angle was constant all the way round therefore removing the problem

Comment: Please consider including some information about your answer, rather than simply posting code. We try to provide not just 'fixes', but help people learn. You should explain what was wrong in the original code, what you did differently, and why your change(s) worked.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using RotateTransforms instead.
Transforms is built into WPF for scaling, rotation, and movements.

See [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750596(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can then use Expression Blend to manage the rotate transitions for you.
Versus coding everything by hand.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the Rotate function uses that. Bit of code I forgot.  Edited the code in